# DATE_SUB date interval

Tags: mysql

I have this `order_createdAt >=  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)` which is returning data from now to 7 days ago. How can I get data from 8 days ago to 14 days ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use between

```
order_createdAt BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
                   AND  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 8  DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `BETWEEN` `AND` to do this:

```
order_createdAt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 8 DAY)
```